# Any other version of WebMarkupMin.Mvc supporting the asp.net mvc2 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have used the WebMarkupMin 0.8.12 in a asp.net mvc2 project for enabling the minification of the html markup. I have used the nuget package to update my project with the WebMarkupMin 0.8.12 components. Installation completed successfully without any errors.

Sample Code:

```
[HandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [CompressContent]
        [MinifyHtml]
        [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "CacheCompressedContent5Minutes")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Now on building the project I see the following error:

Assembly 'WebMarkupMin.Mvc, Version=0.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=99472178d266584b' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' [Path]\packages\WebMarkupMin.Mvc.0.8.1\lib\net40\WebMarkupMin.Mvc.dll

Can anyone help me to know whether there are other versions of the WebMarkupMin for minification of the html markup which will work with asp.net mvc2 project.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 1):

WebMarkupMin.Mvc Version=0.8.1.0 working only with mvc version 3 or 4

Comment: Is there any other alternative or good solution for enabling the minification of the only html markup for asp.net mvc2 project. I am looking for automated approach which will ease the maintenance issues.